# Need to access logged in user from repository layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How to pass the claim current user object into repository layer, while i am using dependency injunction in .net core may application (N Tier using **.Net core**) architecture may be

1. UI
2. API
3. Model
4. Repository
5. Common
6. Database

   In the above API has project dependency with Model,Repository and Common.

My Problem is Claim User (Using JWT Middle ware) need to inject to repository layer so that created_by and modified_by cannot be parameter from API layer code

Comment: What you are asking for? You would like to access the logged in user from repository layer isn't it?

Comment: yes Tanvir, Any help would be great

Comment: You're not using Dependency injection?

Comment: @PalaniKumar You did not ask the question clearly what you actually want! Okay no problem! I have answered your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the `loggedInUserId` in your `Repository Layer` using `IHttpContextAccessor` as follows:

```
public class Repository
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public Repository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
       _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

   public void YourRepositoryMethod()
   {
      var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
      // or
      var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
   }
}
```

Then you should register `IHttpContextAccessor` in the `Startup` class as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // Or you can also register as follows

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```